# port Oracle decode() using variadic, anyarray, and anyelement

Tags: postgresql, polymorphic-functions

I need to port from Oracle a stored procedure that uses `decode()` extensively. That is, I can't use series of `CASE WHEN expr THEN expr [...] ELSE` as the [guide](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Oracle_to_Postgres_Conversion#Decode) suggests.

I wanted to create a variadic function, but here's the problem: in Oracle the function can accept any number of key-value pairs and the type of the key not necessarily matches the type of the value:

```
select decode(0  ,0,'a'  ,1,'b'  ,2,'c'  /*,...*/ ,'dflt') from dual;
```

I tried to use `anyarray`:

```
create or replace function decode(VARIADIC args anyarray) RETURNS text AS $$
  SELECT null::text;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

But this only works when all the arguments are of the same type:

```
select decode(0,0,0); -- ok
select decode('x'::text,'x'::text,'x'::text); -- ok
select decode(0,0,'a'::text); -- No function matches the given name and argument types
```

If the desired syntax is not possible please advise another way of passing the `expr`, the set of pairs, and the default value while keeping their positions same as in Oracle.

Comment: Not an answer but an observation `decode` is a PostgreSQL [system function handling binary string](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-binarystring.html), it might worth not to override the name and change it to another one eg.: `xdecode`.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to emulate Oracle's `decode`, even using C functions. You'll have to touch the `decode`s in your application.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but OraFCE claims to have an Oracle compatiable `decode()` function: https://github.com/orafce/orafce

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe - there are typ "any" available from C extension - and there is possible to emulate any functionality - unfortunately - there is some performance penalty - how much high, it depends on context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Limitation

It seems it is how PostgreSQL is implemented. Reading the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/xfunc-sql.html):

> 35.4.5. SQL Functions with Variable Numbers of Arguments
>
> SQL functions can be declared to accept variable numbers of arguments,
>   so long **as all the "optional" arguments are of the same data type**. The
>   optional arguments will be passed to the function as an array. The
>   function is declared by marking the last parameter as VARIADIC; this
>   parameter must be declared as being of an array type.

#### JSON

If you find a way to export your mixed array into JSON format from Oracle, then [PostgreSQL JSON type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-json.html) will cope with it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION xdecode(data json)
RETURNS TEXT AS
$BODY$
    -- Your implementation here
    SELECT NULL::TEXT;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

This function accepts a JSON string and it can be like:

```
SELECT xdecode('[1, 2, 3.3, "a", true, null]'::json);
```

#### Table Type

If the tuple of arguments you want to decode matches a `TABLE` type, then you can use it:

```
CREATE TABLE foo(
    x INTEGER,
    y FLOAT,
    z TEXT
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION xdecode2(data foo)
RETURNS TEXT AS
$BODY$
    SELECT row_to_json(data)::TEXT;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Then this call works:

```
SELECT xdecode2((1, 2.1, 'x'))
```

Unfortunately we cannot use the generic `RECORD` type as input argument for a function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION xdecode3(data RECORD)
RETURNS TEXT AS
$BODY$
    SELECT row_to_json(data)::TEXT;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Raises:

```
ERROR: SQL functions cannot have arguments of type record
SQL state: 42P13
```

#### Type `anyelement`

As pointed out by @basin, type `RECORD` can be emulated using [`anyelement`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/datatype-pseudo.html):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION xdecode4(data anyelement)
RETURNS TEXT AS
$BODY$
    SELECT row_to_json(data)::TEXT;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE SQL;

SELECT xdecode4((1, 2.1, 'x'));
```

Returns:

```
'{"f1":1,"f2":2.1,"f3":"x"}'
```

Comment: a small note: we can pass a generic `RECORD` to a function of type `SQL`, if the parameter is declared as `anyelement`. We can apply `row_to_json()`, but we can't extract the type info from it.

Comment: @basin Thank you to point this out, will it be enough to solve your problem?